# Getting data from web server with jQuery

Tags: python, jquery, webserver, cherrypy

Here is the scenario: I am getting data from database through web server. Based on that data page sends another request to the same server to perform some action. Simplified structure is the following:

```
var datacon;
$.post('method',function(data){
   datacon = data;
   // populating some tags;
}) // end of post
//some other staff happening;
$.post('other',{datacon}, function(env){
...// taking data from populated tags
   $("div").load(env);
...
}) // end of post
```

This happens every time user enters the page. This code doesn't work in a sense that datacon is empty when the page is opened. But if I will refresh it once or twice, it starts working. Second $.post works perfectly, checked hundreds of times. I changed first $.post with $.get, but it doesn't help.

Probably it concerns asynchronous / synchronous calls. I don't understand much why it happens. Please help.

p.s. server is CherryPy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As these calls are asynchronous, it possible that the second call is running before the first has completed. To ensure that they run in the correct order, place the second ajax call in a done() function at the end of the first. That way, the second will only be run when the first is finished.

Here is a sample from a project I'm working on:

```
    $("#leftcolumn").activity();
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/search",
            cache: false,
            data: {searchterm: searchterm}
            }).done( function(reply) {
                $("#leftcolumn").activity(false);
                showSearchResults(reply);
                });
```

The first line shows a progress indicator on the screen. Then the ajax call does a search. At the end in .done, I then disable the progress indicator I was showing and then display the search results. Putting the code I want to execute in .done guarantees that it won't run until the ajax call is finished.

Comment: Mike, could you please explain a bit more? What is done() function?

Comment: I believe that what Mike is suggesting could just be achieved by moving the second POST into the callback function of the first.

Answer (score 1):

The callback functions are executed asynchronously, that is, once the data is received from the server.  Your second POST is likely being executed before the response from the first POST is returned.  You can change your first post() to ajax() and set the 'async' to 'false'.  See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

The above is a bit kludgy though -- ideally everything that depends on the result of an AJAX call should go in the callback method.  Try moving the second POST inside of the callback of the first one, for example.  The setting of flags like you are trying to do could be considered a code smell.